# Is it sin to listen to Quran recitation in the bathroom?

Tags: halal-haram, quran-recitation

Is it sin to listen to quran recitation on phone in bathroom and toilet? I know it is makrooh (disliked) but is it forbidden in Quran or Hadith? Can you show with evidence?

Answer (score 1):

It is (probably) forbidden.

You can *listen* to recitation while in the bathroom but you should not *recite* while in the bathroom.

According to [source 1](https://mtws.posthaven.com/is-it-permissible-to-listen-to-the-quran-while-in-the-bathroom) and [source 2](https://islamqa.info/en/78370), the speaker or "radio" must be outside of the bathroom, but it is permissible for listeners to hear it from inside the bathroom. Based on that I think we can extrapolate and say that the *sound source* should not originate from inside of the bathroom, which would rule out radios, phones, mp3 players, etc, unless they are placed outside of the bathroom in speaker mode such that you can hear it inside with your ears (not headphones).

That being said, I think this may require further clarification. What if someone is reciting outside of the bathroom, but someone inside the bathroom is wearing a hearing aid? I'd like to think the hearing aid would be allowed, but if so that isn't much different than a loudspeaker or radio inside of the bathroom, and the latter seems to not be allowed.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide an evidence from quran or sunnah as asked by OP.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - you're right, but electronic listening devices did not exist when the Quran was written, so finding evidence there or from the original teachings might not be possible. I think the closest you can get is to look to scholars to interpret the original texts and teachings and apply them to today's society. The links I provided are from known scholars.

Comment: Well the point is what you mentioned are special cases. And we can build on evidences by analogy i guess this is meant by OP and those should be posted here.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Please forgive my ignorance in that regard, as I am new to this site (and to Islam). I thought that scholarly interpretations would be sufficient here, but of course it would be best to have the scholars do the extrapolation for modern listening devices, rather than me trying to guess.

Answer (score -1):

No  you  Should not do that  Because
the  Quran  should not  enter  or to be listened  in the Satans Place
and  satans  places always  be impure

Comment: Salam and welcome to islam SE i strongly recommend you to take your time to leran more about our site and model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help].